# How to open the page in new window using response.redirect in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Can anybody suggest how we can open the page in new window using `Response.Redirect` in c#, I know we can do it using response.write as given below:

```
Response.Write("<script>");
Response.Write("window.open('"+url+"','_blank')");
Response.Write("</script>");
```

But what when javascript is disabled, the above code will not run.

Please suggest!!

Comment: Please show an example of a website that does the redirect without javascript enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tom Gullen suggested that is the only way.
I am assuming you're using ASP.NET.

You can create a public function which receives the Url you want to open in the new windows. 
This function then redirects to a page which does the dirty job.

```
Public Function ResponseRedirect(ByVal urlRedirect As String) As Boolean
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Redirector.aspx?goto=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(urlRedirect))
End Function
```

This is Redirector.aspx

```
Public Partial Class Redirector
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim OpenNewPage As String = ""
        If Request.QueryString("goto") IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.OpenNewPage = Request.QueryString("goto")
        End If
        If Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.Referer = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri
        End If
    End Sub

    Private _OpenNewPage As String = ""
    Public Property OpenNewPage() As String
        Get
            Return _OpenNewPage
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _OpenNewPage = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Referer As String = ""
    Public Property Referer() As String
        Get
            Return _Referer
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Referer = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

and the HTML of Redirector.asp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('<%=Me.OpenNewPage%>', '_blank', '');
    window.document.location.href = '<%=Me.Referer%>';
</script>
```

It's not really really elegant code but it does the trick. 
Obviously, if javascript is disabled it doesn't work.

I've put together a sample [here](http://cid-669adf1af64df389.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/ResponseRedirect.zip).
Hope it helps.

Comment: The OQ specifies there can be no javascript.  How does this help?

Answer (score 3):

Response.redirect can't open a new window, it redirects the clients HTTP request to a new location in the current browser window. This is a limitation of server side, to perform a popup on the client machine you will at some point require client side code (IE, Javascript).

Comment: can you please suggest me using a example!!

Comment: @Manu: No he can't. It's not possible to do it with `Response.Redirect`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can settle for using a ASP:Hyperlink rather than a ASP:Linkbutton or ASP:Button you can handle the navigation a bit easier. Rather than using Response.Redirect during a postback, just build the hyperlink's NavigateURL during Page_Load or some other event:

```
protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lnkViewPage.NavigateURL = sURL;
    lnkViewPage.Target = "_blank";
}
```

Of course it is more polite to leave .Target alone because unlike buttons, linkbuttons, and imagebuttons, hyperlinks can be right clicked and "open in new page/tab" would be available from the context menu, giving the user control of how to handle the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to dynamically open a new window without javascript.

If you want the window to always redirect you can pass back HTML that tells the browser to redirect in the header information.  Like so:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="5; URL=html-redirect.html">
```

Remember this will basically happen right away (or in the case above in 5 seconds).  If you want something to cause the page to go somewhere else without javascript you need a link the user clicks on.

You can add this dynamically in C# like this:

```
Dim reMetaTag As New HtmlMeta
reMetaTag.HttpEquiv = "Refresh"
reMetaTag.Content = "5;URL=http://www.site.com"
Page.Header.Controls.Add(reMetaTag)
```

Comment: There is no logic.  This is part of the HTML not the javascript.  It is just markup.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable javascript and still be able to open a window i suggest you to become a magician.

Using javascript and response.redirect for a server button(for example) without refreshing parent window you should use the following code:

`<input type="button" id="Example" value="Click!" runat="server"`
`onclick="var win = window.open('','Stack','width=500,height=600,menubar=no');`
`document.forms[0].target = 'Stack';" onserverclick="Save" />`

Save function defined in your page behind code would be something like this

```
protected void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //your code here
 Response.Redirect(url);//url it's a string for target url
}
```

So [Tom Gullen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356635/tom-gullen) was wrong and [Manu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30394/manu)'s idea would give you a headache because it refreshes parent page.
Hope this helps somebody. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using http then use below code

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open ('URL','_blank');</script>");
```

this code cannot be used for https for https do below

javascript in page

```
function shwwindow(myurl) {
    window.open(myurl, '_blank');
}
```

in c# code behind

```
 string URL = ResolveClientUrl("~") + "**internal page path**";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "show window", 
"shwwindow('"+URL+"');", true);
```

this code cannot bybass the browser popup blocker. user must allow it to run. for ie it opens in new window or new tab up to ie version in firefox and chrome it opens new tab

enjoy it!!